# Feature collection to image in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a feature collection of conflict events for Iraq in 1999:

```
var events = ee.FeatureCollection('users/salem043/ACLED19Iraq');
```

I would like to transform this feature collection into an image where each band is a day and where the pixels are coded as the number of conflict events at that pixel on a given day. Does anyone know the function that will allow me to do this?

My objective is to use this image to obtain tabular data at the grid-day level of the number of conflict events.

My code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9b77a22b24555e84d1dfa6e2c724b9e3)